# Pipe trouble in C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, ipc

I am currently having trouble with understanding non-duplex two-way unnamed pipe communication between children and their parent. I am attempting to have up to ten children in communication with the super parent.

Currently I am trying to have the super parent say hello to each of the children, then the children say hello back to the parent. Finally, the super parent acknowledges that he received hello from each of the children.

I tested the forks before adding the pipes and they work fine, producing the correct number of children. So I am almost positive the problem is somewhere in one (or both) of the two pipeCommunication() methods at the bottom of my code.

When I run the program, it stands still (as if waiting for an input). I expected it got stuck in a while loop for reading, but **I can't even get the very first line of main() to print.**

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int NUM_CHILDREN;
int ID;


// Create the pipes
void createPipes(int[], int[]);

// Wait for the children processes
void waitForChildren(int);

// The Child pipe communication method
void childPipeCommunication(int, int, int);

// The Parent pipe communication method
void parentPipeCommunication(int, int, int);



// MAIN FUNCTION
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // NOT BEING PRINTED:
    printf("Hello");

    NUM_CHILDREN = argc - 1;

    // The file descriptors for the pipes
    int fd_childReads_ParentWrites[10][2];   // Parent should close 0, Child close 1
    int fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[10][2];   // Child should close 0, Parent close 1

    // Index of the child Array (0 to NUM_CHILDREN-1)
    int user;

    int pid;
    int pidArray[10]; // Stores each of the child's process id's

    // Fork the children and create the pipes
    for(user = 0; user < NUM_CHILDREN; user++)
    {
        // Create the pipes
        createPipes(fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user], fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user]);

        // Fork the children
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)   // Error occurred
        {
            printf("Fork Failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)   // Child
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (pid) // Parent
        {
            pidArray[user] = pid;
        }
    }


    if (pid == 0) // CHILD
    {
        // Close the appropriate pipe ends
        close(fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user][1]);
        close(fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user][0]);

        ID = getpid();
        int n = 0;

        // Enter pipe communication (user is the same as when it broke from the for loop)
        childPipeCommunication(ID, fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user][0],
                                fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user][1]);

        // Finally, close the working child pipe ends
        close(fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user][0]);
        close(fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user][1]);
    }
    else // PARENT
    {
        ID = getpid();
        user = 0;

        // Close the appropriate pipe ends
        for (user = 0; user < NUM_CHILDREN; user++)
        {
            close(fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user][0]);
            close(fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user][1]);
        }

        // Go into Pipe Communication
        for(user = 0; user < NUM_CHILDREN; user++)
        {
            parentPipeCommunication(pidArray[user], fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user][0], fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user][1]);
        }

        // Wait for the children
        waitForChildren();

        // Finally, close the working parent pipe ends
        for (user = 0;  user < NUM_CHILDREN; user++)
        {
            close(fd_childReads_ParentWrites[user][1]);
            close(fd_parentReads_ChildWrites[user][0]);
        }
    }
}



void createPipes(int fd1[2], int fd2[2])
{
    if (pipe(fd1) < 0)
    {
        printf("Pipe creation error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pipe(fd2) < 0)
    {
        printf("Pipe creation error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}


void waitForChildren()
{
    int user;
    for (user = 0; user < NUM_CHILDREN; user++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Here are the methods for pipe communication.

```
void childPipeCommunication(int childID, int fdReadFromParent, int fdWriteToParent)
{
    char buf_ChildReads[80];  
    int n = 0;

    while ((n = read(fdReadFromParent, buf_ChildReads, 80)) > 0)
        {
            buf_ChildReads[n] = 0;

            // CASE: CHILD RECEIVES HELLO FROM PARENT
            if(strcmp(buf_ChildReads, "Hi child.\n") == 0)
            {
                // Remove new line character
                buf_ChildReads[--n] = 0;

                // Acknowledge parent's hello and then send reply
                printf("Child %d: Reveived message [%s] from parent\n", childID, buf_ChildReads);
                write(fdWriteToParent, "Hello Parent\n", 13);
            }
        }
}


void parentPipeCommunication(int childID, int fdReadFromChild, int fdWriteToChild)
{
    char buf_ParentReads[80];  
    int n = 0;

    // Say hello to the child
    write(fdWriteToChild, "Hi child\n", 9);

    // Engage in communication with the child
    while ((n = read(fdReadFromChild, buf_ParentReads, 80)) > 0)
        {
            buf_ParentReads[n] = 0;

            // CASE: PARENT RECEIVES HELLO FROM CHILD
            if(strcmp(buf_ParentReads, "Hello Parent\n") == 0)
            {
                printf("Parent: I have received response from child %d\n", childID);
            }
        }
}
```

If anyone can look at my code and tell me how to correctly implement communication between parent and children, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: the value '10' is all over the code, and is (implicitly) expecting the number of parameters to be 10.  However, there is no check in the code to assure that assumption.  it would be far better to either ignore command line parameters completely (they are not being used for anything other than a count.) --or-- modify all those arrays to use the count.

Comment: @user, thanks for your help. However, this is only part of the code. I have plenty more going on with those values, but I only wanted to include the pipe communication primarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set NUM_CHILDREN to the number of command line arguments.  If you fail to supply any arguments then it is zero, the loop is not entered, pid is uninitialized and it is undefined which of the two paths at the bottom will be taken.  Both will hang though.

When using printf in a situation where you are not reading from stdin and hanging is happening, you may need to use `fflush` to get output.

Next, your parent is expecting a message without a period, and your child is sending the period.

Finally, both parent and child are looping until the other closes so communication from the first child doesn't end and later children are never processed.

Comment: Thanks for the info on cmd line args. I do have verification in my code, just did not add it to here, there will always between 3 and 10 children.

Anyway, that period was definitely a problem, after adding it, you are correct and the other children do not go into communication. Can you provide a solution on how to be in constant communication with all the children? Or something like that?

Comment: Doesn't this line exit the loop when the child does not have anything left to say?

`while ((n = read(fdReadFromChild, buf_ParentReads, 80)) > 0)`

And similarly for when the child reads() from parent?

Comment: I think I have an idea of how to get around it. Thank you.

Comment: That line only exits if the other end closes the pipe.  You need a condition/command to trigger that.

Answer (score 2):

1) Issue: printf not being printed:

`stdout` is typically line buffered under Unix. Try printing to `stderr` (unbuffered), call `fflush(stdout)`, or explicitly print the `"\n"`.

2) Issue: write & strcmp

Note that you `write(fd, "Hi child\n", 9)` without trailing `'\0'`, yet strcmp compares zero terminated strings. Your child processes therefore never respond.

Bidirectional IPC via pipes has many pitfalls. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer